# Is there a way to bookmark useful StackExchange threads from within my profile?

Tags: feature-request

Ok, this may sound a little old-school, but I come across so many threads that I think may be useful in the future or for other tasks and I want to simply click a button, to have them bookmarked for later use in my profile.

Yes, I know there are tons of bookmarking services, but I think something like this could be very useful across the Stack Exchange family of sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a litte star on the left side. Click it, and you'll find these *favorites* in your profile under - well - *favorites*. [Example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho?tab=favorites&sort=newest&StartDate=2012-03-21%2018:00:54Z).

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Bainternet I would like to know what tool you used to take the screenshot. I like the arrow. Not many screenshot tools have proper arrows.

Comment: Actually its infuriated web based editor